# Passing Nullable To Web Methods C#

Tags: c#, web-services, c#-4.0, web

Is it possible to pass a nullable parameter to a webservice ?

I tried with this method :

```
 [WebMethod]
        public Response<bool> IsAColor(bool? isRed, bool? isYellow, bool? isBlue, bool? isBlack)
        {
            ...
        }
```

And i get this error : System.FormatException: Value 'null' cannot be converted to type 'Boolean'.

Thanks !

Comment: Where are you getting this error? How are you invoking the web service?

Comment: i tested it with SoapUi : '<num:IsAColor>
         <num:isRed>null</num:isRed>
         <num:isYellow>false</num:isYellow>
         <num:isBlue>false</num:isBlue>
         <num:isBlack>true</num:isBlack>
      </num:IsAColor>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After showing the way you are invoking your web service in SoapUI the problem is the following line:

```
<num:isRed>null</num:isRed>
```

That's invalid boolean value. Remove this tag completely if you want to pass null to the `isRed` parameter.

Like this:

```
<num:IsAColor>
    <num:isYellow>false</num:isYellow> 
    <num:isBlue>false</num:isBlue> 
    <num:isBlack>true</num:isBlack> 
</num:IsAColor>
```

Comment: @ahikaz, glad I could help. If this answer was helpful make sure to [mark it as such](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the green tick next to it.